# InAppUpdate deprecated

Tags: java, android

appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult is deprecated and is replace by:

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
    // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
    appUpdateInfo,
    // an activity result launcher registered via registerForActivityResult
    activityResultLauncher,
    // Or pass 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' to newBuilder() for
    // flexible updates.
    AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE).build());
```

Anyone know how to resolve activityResultLauncher

Regards